# How to add a certificate to a local Outlook contact using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, certificate

I am trying to sort out current contacts in Outlook to replace encryption certificates. But it is not clear how to prepare the object?

```
 # В var $contactList collect contacts from Outlook
foreach ( $name in $contactList ) {

                 $PR_x509_Certificate = ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A701102');              

# Create new contact
                 $NewContact = $Outlook.CreateItem('olContactItem');
# Get email, name, fullname from old contact                 
                 $NewContact.Email1Address        = $name.Email1Address; 
                 $NewContact.FullName             = $name.FullName;
                 $NewContact.FirstName            = $name.FirstName;                               
# Import certificate from из .cer file              
                 $NewCertUser = New-Object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2;
                 $NewCertUser.Import($PathToCerFile);
# Try add sertificate, but no success :(               
                 $result = $NewCertUser.RawData;
                 $o = New-Object BuildProperty($result);
                 $NewContact.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty($PR_x509_Certificate, $o);             
# Save new contact                
                 $NewContact.Save();
# Delete old                
                 $name.Delete();

            }
```

I'm trying to update this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do that on the users certificate store `certmgr.msc` without even touching Outlook:

[image: Other people store]

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I need to add a certificate to Outlook to send encrypted messages. But they are not stored in the system storage, but directly in the PST file. Maybe I'm wrong, but the certificates in the system store and in Outlook do not intersect.